# Modeling observation for probabilistic programming language with free Monads

Tags: haskell, monads, dsl, free-monad

I am trying to implement a DST for probablistic programming inspired by [Jared Tobin blog post](https://jtobin.io/simple-probabilistic-programming).

A free monad for a DST including the bernoulli and beta distribution could look like this:

```hs
data ModelF r =
    BernoulliF Double (Bool -> r)
  | BetaF Double Double (Double -> r)
  deriving (Functor)

type Model = Free ModelF

bernoulli :: Double -> Model Bool
bernoulli p = liftF (BernoulliF p id)

beta :: Double -> Double -> Model Double
beta a b = liftF (BetaF a b id)
```

I would like to extend it to support observation on distributions. That is: force a specific return value.

First attempt was to extend the functor:

```
data ModelF r =
    BernoulliF Double (Bool -> r)
  | BetaF Double Double (Double -> r)
  | ObsF (ModelF r) r
  deriving (Functor)
```

This is problematic however since it allows for a recursive nesting of `ObsF`.

One solution would be to lift the free monad into another free monad representing an observed value:

```
data ObsModelF r =
    PureF (Model r)
  | ObsF (Model r) r
  deriving (Functor)

observe :: Model r -> r -> Free ObsModelF r
observe model o = liftF (ObsF model o)
```

The syntax I am after though is:

```
let dist = do
      p <- beta 1 1
      observe (bernoulli p) True
```

This is incompatible with `ObsModelF` since `beta 1 1` should also be lifted into `ObsModelF`. This requires two separate constructors: one for distributions without an observation and one with an observation. Is it possible to avoid that complexity in the DST?

---

A third attempt. This time I wrap the distribution functor (`ModelF`) in the observation functor that I then lift (`ObsModelF`). 
I get some type errors I do not quite understand though (see the comments):

```
data ModelF r =
    BernoulliF Double (Bool -> r)
  | BetaF Double Double (Double -> r)
  deriving (Functor)

data ObsModelF r =
    PureF (ModelF r)
  | ObsF (ModelF r) r
  deriving (Functor)

type ObsModel = Free ObsModelF

bernoulli :: Double -> ObsModel Bool
bernoulli p = liftF . PureF $ BernoulliF p id

beta :: Double -> Double -> ObsModel Double
beta a b = liftF . PureF $ BetaF a b id

observe :: ObsModel r -> r -> ObsModel r
observe f o = liftF $ case f of
           (Free f') -> case f' of
               (PureF f'') ->  ObsF f'' o   -----| Couldn't match expected type ‘Free ObsModelF r’
               (ObsF f'' o') ->  ObsF f'' o    --| with actual type ‘r’

toSampler :: (RandomGen g) => ObsModel r -> State g r
toSampler = iterM $ \case
  ObsF a o -> case a of 
    BernoulliF p f -> return o >>= f  -----| Couldn't match type ‘StateT g Data.Functor.Identity.Identity r’
    BetaF a b f    -> return o >>= f     --| with ‘Bool’
  PureF a -> case a of 
    BernoulliF p f -> MWC.bernoulli p >>= f
    BetaF a b f    -> MWC.beta a b >>= f
```

I have included a very simple interpreter (`toSampler`). Currently it ignores the distribution completely and just flatmaps the observation value. Please note that this is not the intended behaviour when conditioning on a distribution. It is only provided to show how the interpreter would traverse the free structure.

Comment: I'm unsure about the semantics you expect from the `ObsModelF` type. Could you write an interpreter to clarify? Also, what is wrong with wrapping `beta 1 1` using `PureF` or a `lift`-like function?

Comment: I would like to `observe` an arbitrary distribution. If I lifted all distribution with `Pure` (both bernoulli and beta) I would have to unwrap bernoulli to lift it with `ObsF` again. 

It seems like a lot of operations for a simpel task. What I want to achieve is fixing a `ModelF r` return value by "labeling" it as observed. I can try and elaborate more in the question body..

Comment: From reading the blog post and a few more materials I have some idea of what it means to `observe` but I can't reconcile that with your type at the moment, hence why I asked to have an interpreter to look at. Furthermore, wrapping/unwrapping can usually be hidden pretty easily from the language user, but it's easier to figure out an appropriate way to clean up the API if there is a working implementation first.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I have updated the answer with a third attempt that includes an interpreter. I would really appreciate it if you could take a look and help me understand what is wrong.

Comment: You can use `ObsF !(ModelF r) r` if you want to make sure it doesn't nest indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with something similar in other languages/DSLs. I'm not sure the thing I have in mind is exactly what you're after, but I'll give a rough sketch of the idea. Maybe you'll find it helpful.

The `observe` I'm familiar with has a type something like `Distribution a -> a -> Model ()`, and it is interpreted as multiplying the probability of the current path through the model by the probability(/density) of the observation under the distribution. This `observe` takes a `Distribution`, rather than a `Model`, as we need a way to compute the probability(/density) of the observation.

Once you have a `Distribution` type, you can also replace the per distribution operations with a single operation for introducing uncertainty. This would take a `Distribution` as argument.

I have a Haskell DSL that works in pretty much this way [here](https://github.com/null-a/tyche). The only difference is that `observe` is [implemented](https://github.com/null-a/tyche/blob/ac851be52cf01c4acbb62802c3314aa1173e750b/src/Tyche/Prelude.hs#L12-L13) in terms of a simpler operation called [`weight`,](https://github.com/null-a/tyche/blob/ac851be52cf01c4acbb62802c3314aa1173e750b/src/Tyche/Model.hs#L41-L45) which arbitrarily modifies the log probability of the current path.

BTW, this approach is lifted in its entirety from the [WebPPL](http://webppl.org) language.

Comment: Looks like a really nice port – I'll definitely have a closer look. You should also check out https://github.com/adscib/monad-bayes if you haven't already. There seem to be a few similarities. It also looks like they have started adding single-site MH which was not part of the original paper.

My interpreter will eventually map it to a single-site MH so an observation should fix the `logPdf` and `sample` for a given distribution. I'm struggling to understand how this can be modelled as a free monad though – would you stack the free monad?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion

```
data ModelF r =
    BernoulliF Double (Bool -> r)
  | BetaF Double Double (Double -> r)
  | ObsFail
  deriving (Functor)
```

Then you can do

```
let dist = do
      p <- beta 1 1
      b <- bernoulli p
      if (b==True)
          then return ()
          else ObsFail
```

In general, we can define

```
observe dist r = do
    r' <- dist
    if r == r'
        then return ()
        else ObsFail
```

To sample, we sample like normal, except we re-sample it each time we get `ObsFail`.